# AND / OR gates implementation (real or educational)

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, cmos

Frank Vahid's "Digital Design" book presents AND and OR gates at the transistor level like this:

[image]

Disregarding how it hurts the eyes to see them upside-down like this, is this purely educational/historical or real and current implementations can actually be found with this topology?

The modern datasheets I've searched don't even bother showing simplified internal (transistor based) diagrams, but this [one](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AHC_AHCT1G32.pdf) (2-inputs OR gate) seems to indicate that the intrinsic inversion/amplification of the CMOS pair (NAND, NOR, NOT) is more desirable:

[image]

This [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/226026/281324) explains that it really "works", but criticizes the implementation as well as the other answer points some problems. The book mentioned above may be the source of the lecture note mentioned in the question.

Comment: The diagrams from the book are wrong unless those would be some very special purpose gates. As the output swings to the target voltage, the output devices will go into subthreshold operation, and the output will become high impedance. That's not normally desired.

Comment: Assuming the leakage currents are very low to being with, and the devices are cold, if the output was driving only a MOS gate, it would swing lazily for a bit, and then very slowly creep towards the rail of the output logic state, possibly for a long time. The gate being subject to this "input" would not be very happy at all, and might oscillate as the gate impedance would be rather high.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using NMOS transistors as pull-up devices and PMOS transistors as pull-down devices is not something that people do for normal designs.

The majority of digital design is based on the principles of static CMOS logic design. That results in the output reaching VDD/VSS with a consistent, static drive strength.

A NMOS transistor will not pull the output all the way to VDD. The *next* logic gate (if the output is a logic '1') will have an even lower voltage. You have a limited number of stages that this gimmick will work. This misconception often comes up when people learn that a transistor is a "switch", without any details or nuance on how that switch works.

For example, consider the schematic below. This uses discrete transistors that were randomly available, but we have the NMOS pull-up (2N7000), and the PMOS pull-down (BSS84).I have included 3 stages to demonstrate that this logic configuration "works", but is unsuitable for use in a larger system *because it doesn't drive the next stage as well*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftVrum.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Now if I use the same transistors in a standard "Static CMOS" configuration, my voltages are driven rail to rail. In fact, a signal that is less than the 5 V square wave would be amplified.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjzkwL.png)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The schematics have an obvious mistake (NMOS and PMOS mixed up, and the whole thing is drawn only to confuse).

Assuming the schematic was corrected first:

Yes, definitely real implementations can be found - but they would typically be buried inside of an IC. Such a gate is not ready to be interfaced to the outside world - at least not if performance is of any concern. It's similar to unbuffered 40xx series logic - mostly a poor performer and these days mostly obsolete. But as a functional block in an IC, it is often sufficient.

The schematic in question is a bit incomplete, though, and the missing detail makes all the difference. In integrated transistor-level design, transistors aren't like discrete devices that are "black boxes", with fixed specifications. They are more like resistors: they have a "value". In fact, they have several key values, but at a minimum, the basic value would be either **drive strength** or **channel width-to-length ratio (W/L)**. They are not exactly equivalent, and the choice of one over the other depends on convenience. Drive strength would be of more use in digital circuits, whereas W and L (width and length) or at least W/L is needed for analog IC design.

Now, I don't particularly care about trivial examples that are copy-pasted all over the place: I will hope to show something that's more representative of contemporary research.

First, I'll cite pulse amplifiers from [Marly Roncken and Ivan Sutherland: Design and test of high-speed asynchronous circuits (pdf link)](https://arc.cecs.pdx.edu/sites/all/uploads/Publications/RonckenSutherland_Chapter07_AsynchronousCircuitApplications_IET2020.pdf):

[image]

Here, drive strength is used as a specification, it is given relative to some unit drive strength. You can then see something like "3" or "3x", meaning the drive strength is 3 units, where 1 unit would be some minimum.

The bold transistors are considered to be "drivers", whereas the thin-lined ones are "weak keepers", i.e. switchable pull-ups/pull-downs.

Another nice example are arbiter circuits. The figure below, from [the same source](https://arc.cecs.pdx.edu/sites/all/uploads/Publications/RonckenSutherland_Chapter07_AsynchronousCircuitApplications_IET2020.pdf), shows both the icon-al depiction of the arbiter's functionality as well as its transistor-level schematic. Transistor sizing in this application is further described in detail in [this paper](https://arc.cecs.pdx.edu/sites/all/uploads/Publications/MettalaGilla_MEsizing_TCAS2019.pdf), fully referenced below.

[image]

As you can see, there aren't all that many transistors per gate, and the circuit looks very similar in design principles to the one you had shown.

On an IC, transistors used for digital logic are very much "analog", meaning that they don't *necessarily* get damaged if multiple outputs with "conflicting" states drive the same node. The transistors are sized usually so that one of them "wins", and the dissipation on the others is limited, since they inherently act like current sources. Say, a transistor with a drive strength of 30 will always win with a transistor of drive strength 1: the latter can almost be considered a switchable pull-up/down resistor.

The heaviest loads that need high drive strengths are usually wires ("traces") that connect to other parts of the die, but gate capacitance also matters.

A so-called [*theory of logical effort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_effort) can be used for device sizing in practical transistor-level gate design.

The application of this approach to the arbiter circuit shown above is discussed in the paper: [Swetha Mettala Gilla, Marly Roncken, Ivan Sutherland, and Xiaoyu Song: Mutual Exclusion Sizing for Hoi Polloi (pdf link)](https://arc.cecs.pdx.edu/sites/all/uploads/Publications/MettalaGilla_MEsizing_TCAS2019.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. The diagrams are similar to what I'd consider "normal" with the NMOS devices connected to the lower potential and PMOS ones to positive voltage. What bothers me is that the diagrams for AND and OR connect the PMOS transistors to the lower potential and the NMOS to the higher one.

Answer (score 10):

Typically modern CMOS gates eg. 4001B have an inverting buffer (or two in series) feeding the output, but otherwise are similar to your diagrams. You can still get the unbuffered versions which now have attracted the suffix UB (the 4-gate [CD4001UB](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4001ub.pdf) internal schematic is shown, each of the 2-input NOR gates is identical to the 'Australia view' first schematic in your question):

[image]

There are also protection networks on the inputs and various  parasitic junctions that are formed as part of the semiconductor process, but they don't typically enter into the functional behavior.

Comment: Going down another level, generally to what extent does the arrangement of dopants resemble what you'd imagine from a transistor-level diagram?

Comment: @Dannie That sounds like a completely different question, which you are welcome to ask.

Comment: The dopants are in a different shape, but they necessarily have to be logically equivalent? For examples you can find various "die shots" of simple and complex chips, and the extremely impressive Visual 6502 http://visual6502.org/JSSim/index.html

Comment: Thank you! This diagram matches what the book shows for NOR gates (similarly for NAND). What bothers me is that the diagrams for AND and OR connect the PMOS transistors to the lower potential and the NMOS to the higher one.

Comment: If they have a negative voltage for ‘1’ then it will work and the circuit is right-side up. This would be sort of justified if you’re talking about CMOS connected to ECL with -5.2V supply.

Answer (score 9):

The diagrams are epically wrong.

- VDD and Vss need to be swapped, otherwise the transistors won’t bias correctly (assuming enhancement-mode FETs.)
- Having done that, the ‘AND’ shown is actually a NAND, the ‘OR’ actually an NOR.

I’m very surprised that diagram made it into a textbook. Seriously, the designs shown are dead on arrival.

More here: [CMOS (wrong) OR gate with 4 transistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/560142/cmos-wrong-or-gate-with-4-transistors)

Now that’s squared away, what’s shown in datasheets may include additional inversion plus buffering to yield an output of appropriate type. The '1G32 positive-logic OR gate shown has input and output buffering, which must be accounted for since each buffer also inverts. That is, the '1G32 is internally a NAND that has been [DeMorgan-ized](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/demorgan.html) to an OR.

Typically, in CMOS design the NAND, NOR and NOT are the fundamental gate blocks. At the chip level you will see the classic 4-FET structure for the 2-input gates. [And-or-invert (AOI), or-and-invert (OAI)](http://www.vlsi-expert.com/2018/01/aoi-and-or-inverter-cell.html) and [multiplexers](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/multiplexer) round out the basic logic set in standard cell libraries, as these can be efficiently rendered in CMOS.